# How to select values from li elements in Cheerio/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, cheerio

```html
<div class="tabs__content tabs__content--bg js-tab-panel">
<div class="tabs__panel tabs__panel--active">
   <div class="product__sizes-wrapper">
      <ul class="product__sizes-select js-size-select-list" data-locale="UK">
         <li class="product__sizes-option" data-msg="Sample Message" data-name="6"  data-value="060">
            <span class="product__sizes-size">
            <span class="product__sizes-size-1">6</span>
            <span class="product__sizes-size-2"></span>
            </span>
         </li>
         <li class="product__sizes-option" data-msg="Sample Message" data-name="7"  data-value="070">
            <span class="product__sizes-size">
            <span class="product__sizes-size-1">7</span>
            <span class="product__sizes-size-2"></span>
            </span>
         </li>
         <li class="product__sizes-option" data-msg="Sample Message" data-name="8"  data-value="080">
            <span class="product__sizes-size">
            <span class="product__sizes-size-1">8</span>
            <span class="product__sizes-size-2"></span>
            </span>
         </li>
         <li class="product__sizes-option" data-msg="Sample Message" data-name="9.5"  data-value="095">
            <span class="product__sizes-size">
            <span class="product__sizes-size-1">9.5</span>
            <span class="product__sizes-size-2"></span>
            </span>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract the values from the `product__sizes-size-1` classes and transform them into an array. I have tried to use a .map() function to try and populate an array but it appears empty. To make it clear I want to have the array populated like [6,7,8,9.5] etc...

```js
const sizes = $(".product__sizes-wrapper [data-locale = 'UK']").map(function() {
                        return $(this).text();
                     }).get();
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.  Keeping in mind that you don't have values.  You have data attributes, one of which has a key of value.  They are not the same thing.

Comment: Shown what I have attempted

Comment: Err, the element with the data-locale on it is the `ul`, of which there is only one. What exactly are you trying to make a list of?

Comment: The data values from the class product__sizes-size-1 (9.5,8,7) etc

Comment: I edited my OG post for clarity @Taplar

Comment: So change your selector to find those guys.  You can't stop your selector on the parent element if you want to map over a list of children.  Find the children and map over them.  `$(".product__sizes-wrapper [data-locale = 'UK'] .product__sizes-size-1").map(...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226155/discussion-between-scene-and-taplar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you just use the wrong selector. Use `product__sizes-size-1` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sizes = $('.product__sizes-size-1').map(function(){return $(this).text()}).get();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select it
`$('#product__sizes-select li.product__sizes-size-1');`

In array

```
var product_sizes = [];
$('ul').each(function() {
    var localproduct_sizes = [];
    $(this).find('li').each(function(){
        localproduct_sizes.push( $(this).attr('product__sizes-size-1') );
    });
    product_sizes.push(localproduct_sizes);
});
```

Comment: I am getting undefined for every value in the array